# Jquery help inserting HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I rewrite this insert html Jquery:

```
var element = findLastInput(this).clone();
element.insertAfter(findLastInput(this));
```

This is the HTML

To insert it after inside the closest div with the class `button-row`.

My HTML:

```
<div class="input numeric integer optional">
    <label for="company_webserver" class="integer optional"> Webserver</label>
    <input type="number" step="1" size="50" name="company[webserver]" id="company_webserver" class="numeric integer optional">
</div>
<div class="button-row" style="font-size: 11px; width: 110px; float: right; margin-top: -10px; margin-right: 16px;">
    <button style="font-size: 11px;" type="button" class="add">Add info</button>
    <button style="font-size: 11px;" type="button" class="remove">Remove</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `this` refer to? What is `element`?

Comment: What do you mean by "closest"?

Comment: @Felix - I have updated my question with further very needed information

Comment: @Rails beginner, not sure if you had a look at my answer. I think it is what you need. I am not sure what both functions you defined do, but it appears that you can use the jQuery alternatives in my answer for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution however is jQuery's nextAll method, I assume that you are trying to find the closest '.button-row' after 'this' and are then trying to append 'someHtml':

```
jQuery(this).nextAll('.button-row:first').append(someHtml);
```

Comment: I removed this fromt he answer to make it more concise: I don't really understand what you are trying to do, but try:

    jQuery('.button-row:first').append(someHtml);

You mentioned 'the closest div' I think you want to achieve that the next button-row will be appended to. In that case, if possible, it would probably be easiest to wrap both of them inside the same div, so you can do:

    jQuery('.button-row:first', jQuery(this).parent()).append(someHtml);

This will use the scope of the first div's parent to select the .button-row.

Comment: I did use $(this).closest('.button-row').append(element);

Comment: @Rails, keep in mind that closest will go UP the DOM tree and will also match on the element itself! Apart from that, glad I could help.